# Laravel validator not differntiating between number and string

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have controller whose validator is

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'activation_status' =>'required|in:0,1|integer',
        'is_tkr' =>'required|in:0,1|integer',
     ]);
```

but even if I pass string that is '0' or '1' it still passes.
What is that i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is expected behaviour. You might want to validate also URL variables and they always are strings but you want to make sure `1929` string can be converted to integer. Under the hood [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) method is used.